# how to change type to numeric in r?

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
> head(duomframe)
            DNSB.Ražuva X1 X1.1 X0 X0.1 X40 X8.013.54 X1.2 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X0.5
1 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    1  0    0  51    511,55    0    1    0    0    0
2 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  54    519,46    0    1    0    0    0
3 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  42     492,7    0    1    0    0    0
4 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  51    515,68    0    0    0    0    0
5 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  49  2.308,78    0    1    0    0    0
6 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  63    381,75    0    1    0    0    0
  X0.6 X7.197.16 X78.23 X4 X1.3 X0.7 X0.8 X7.783.31 X2 X1.4 X42.22 X14 X33.33
1    0         0  86.80  2    4    0    0    173,36  1    1  58.31   5 189,79
2    0         0  53.67  1    2    0    3    204,85  0    1  66.29   2    140
3    0         0  52.13  2    3    0    0    160,73  0    2  93.69   2 119,03
4    1    415,68  45.19  3    1    2    0    641,54  0    1  53.56   6 102,11
5    0         0 103.44  3    1    3    0    113,08  0    2 122.45   5 527,61
6    0         0  49.75  4    3    0    0    384,62  0    3  75.09   3  69,46
  X0.9 X12
1    0   4
2    1   3
3    2   4
4    0   6
5    0   5
6    1   4
```

and i need to change all columns except the first one from character type to numeric. I have found info about transforming one column but here i have much more. I even though, i tried to use written tips for one column, but it didn't work.

For example, `transform(duomframe, place = as.numeric(place))` 
(here place is the second column marked with 0 and 1 values). 
In this way I get only na meanings.

I tried also this by creating fake data:

```
place2<-duomframe[place]
d <- data.frame(place2 = place[1:421], 
                fake_place = as.character(1:421), 
                fac = factor(1:421), 
                place_fac = factor(letters[1:421]), 
                num = 1:421, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
transform(d, fake_place = as.numeric(fake_place), place_fac = as.numeric(place_fac))
```

but it also doesn't work

```
mydata<-duomframe
mydata <- within(mydata, { 
        place <- as.numeric(as.character(place)) 
        man <- as.numeric(as.character(man)) 
        ....
})
```

this one as well

There are 421 rows in my data and 27 columns.

Comment: Could try `duomframe[, -1] <- sapply(duomframe[, -1], as.numeric)`. BTW, all your columns are of class `character` or there are `factor`s too? You may want to provide `str(duomframe)`

Comment: @Lauryna  Does those `,` inside numbers represent `decimals`?

Comment: @akrun, good catch re `,`, didn't notice them

Comment: duomframe[, -1] <- sapply(duomframe[, -1], as.numeric) works but in the 7th, 14th, 15th, 20th, 25th columns it changes values.
And yes, all of them are character

Comment: yes, Those represents decimals.But does it have influence for changing values? Because there are columns with these , but values in them were not changed.

Comment: If those are decimals and everything is `character` type, the folowing should work `duomframe[, -1] <- sapply(duomframe[, -1], function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", x)))`

Comment: It still leaves changed values like that

Comment: X1 X1.1 X0 X0.1 X40 X8.013.54 X1.2 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X0.5 X0.6 X7.197.16
1    1    1  0    0  51       275    0    1    0    0    0    0         1
2    1    0  1    0  54       280    0    1    0    0    0    0         1
3    1    0  1    0  42       260    0    1    0    0    0    0         1
4    1    0  1    0  51       279    0    0    0    0    0    1       100
5    1    0  1    0  49        96    0    1    0    0    0    0         1

Comment: @Lauryna. If that represent decimals, what would be `2.308,78` from column `X8.013.54`?

Comment: There should be 511,55 in the place of 51155.0000 , 519,46 in the place of 51946.000 and so on. Sorry, if i didn't understand you correctly

Comment: @Lauyna.  My point is that `2.308,78` already have a decimal so, it is confusing when you said that `,` represent decimals.  Also, is it `511.55`, `519.46` etc?  This is really confusing...

Comment: I got it, i have data in excel and there was 1000 searator.If you remove it, everything is ok. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
 duomframe[,-1] <- lapply(duomframe[,-1], function(x) {as.numeric(gsub(",", "", x))})
 duomframe[1:5, 1:7]
 #            DNSB.Ražuva X1 X1.1 X0 X0.1 X40   X8.013.54
 #1 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    1  0    0  51 51155.00000
 #2 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  54 51946.00000
 #3 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  42  4927.00000
 #4 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  51 51568.00000
 #5 UAB Antakalnio būstas  1    0  1    0  49     2.30878
```